# How do I get the value of different spans in the same jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code:

PHP:

```php
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'In Process'):?>                                    
    <span class="badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">In Process</span>                                  
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Test'): ?>
    <span class="badge" style="background-color:#FCB529">In Test</span>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Approved'):?>
    <span class="badge" style="background-color:#43A995">Approved</span>                                                            
<?php endif;?>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.approved').on('click', function(){
        var process = $('.badge').html();       
        alert(process);     
    });//Onclick
});
```

Button:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="flex-icon approved" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="approve" data="5"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And I'm trying to get the text of the `<span>` tags, but every time I try to get it, it alerts the same text.

How do I get the value of different `<span>` tags in the same jQuery function?

Comment: `.html()` as default return html of first index of selector. So what is `.approved` in your code?

Comment: @Mohammad class of my button, but if i change `<span class="badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">In Process</span>` to `<span class="process badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">In Process</span>` and `var process = $('.badge').html(); ` to `var process = $(this).find('.process').html();` it will try to get all `<span>` tags.

Comment: Do you want to get text of all span?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes! one at time whe i click on button, but it's a list `<ul><li>` tags, on a foreach.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xbzdwpcp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the jquery as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.approved').on('click', function(){
        $('span.badge').each(function() {
            alert( $(this).html());
        });       

    });//Onclick
});
```